# UIWebSelectionAssistant document: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with HTML5 page I load from file. This page has 2 textareas. I focus on the first textarea, then double tap the second textarea and get the below exception:

> ```
> 2012-03-24 11:49:19.354 MyApp[38997:707] -[UIWebSelectionAssistant document]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10fa80
> 2012-03-24 11:49:19.356 MyApp[38997:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> ```
>
> '-[UIWebSelectionAssistant document]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x10fa80'

The exception is not random and I get it every time on iPhone 5.0 and on simulator 4.3. Does anybody know the reason of this error?

Comment: It appears as though you are making a call to a selector (method/property) of UIWebSelectionAssistant that does not exist. Can you post any code?